# Zend Sessions: Dealing with http://www.domain.com vs. http://domain.com

Tags: mod-rewrite, dns, session

What's the best way to handle this? When a user logs in a domain.com, they are logged out on www.domain.com and vice-versa.

Should one always be rewritten to the other with mod_rewrite? What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

I have a few domains that all point to the same website, and I bounce people with a [HTTP Status 301 (Permanent Redirect)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) to my preferred domain.